# rqt plugin not listed/found in list returned by "rqt --list-plugins"

Tags: ros, rqt-gui, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing a rqt plugin (ROS Hydro, Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, x86_64) at moment following the rqt tutorial: Create your new plugin.

Unfortunately, my plugin is not in the list returned by "rqt --list-plugins". rosrun also fails.

$ cd ~/rqt_ws/

$ catkin_make

$ rosrun rqt_mypkg rqt_mypkg

qt_gui_main() found no plugin matching "rqt_mypkg"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91231/rqt-plugin-not-listed/found-in-list-returned-by-%22rqt---list-plugins%22/) by [Gripen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7776/gripen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2013-10-15

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chief_534](https://answers.ros.org/users/5677/chief_534/) on 2013-10-17**:
I'm having the same issue using ROS Groovy.  Everything builds and installs properly, but I can't run the plug-in. I can even open and build it without issue in QT Creator.  I'm currently running off of the binary packages.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Appears to be a problem with rqt caching the locations of plugins in its config and not updating that info. A workaround that works for me is delete that cache and restart rqt:

```
$ rm ~/.config/ros.org/rqt_gui.ini
$ rqt
```

A 2nd workaround: this appears to work using the latest rqt source (groovy-devel branch, which is also used to build the hydro packages), so this looks like a bug in the released packages as opposed to a problem with the tutorial. I added the following to my hydro workspace:

```
- git: {local-name: qt_gui_core, uri: 'git@github.com:ros-visualization/qt_gui_core.git'}
- git: {local-name: rqt, uri: 'git@github.com:ros-visualization/rqt.git'}
- git: {local-name: rqt_common_plugins, uri: 'git@github.com:ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins.git'}
```

and a new plugin was found and ran.

---

Originally posted by [markpitchless](https://answers.ros.org/users/1668/markpitchless/) with karma: 390 on 2013-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 30

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Frederik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1545/frederik/) on 2013-10-26**:
I have the same setup as the initiator (ROS Hydro, Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, x86_64) and face exactly the same problem.

Also overlaying the proposed meta-packages did not solve the problem.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-11-04**:
This might be a bug. Follow this issue for details: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt/issues/90 .

**Comment by [zsbhaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13451/zsbhaha/) on 2014-04-19**:
Thank you very much ! The problem had confused me a long time .

**Comment by [dennis.tryk](https://answers.ros.org/users/19947/dennis.tryk/) on 2014-08-06**:
I am having the same problem. When you say you've added this to your hydro workspace, how exactly is that done. I am working in ROS Groovy.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-06**:
If you follow the bug in question, the fix for this is to add the `--force-discover` option when running rqt.

**Comment by [Mike Zobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/25201/mike-zobot/) on 2018-04-20**:
Just want to say thank you ! I even tried to reinstall ros but doesn't work. Because the config file never been removed....